# Worn saddles on Floyd-Rose bridge break my strings

Tags: electric-guitar, lutherie

I have two Cort guitars with the same type of Floyd Rose bridge. One is about 5 years older than another. Each of them has the same problem. The saddles are worn due to friction with the strings. It makes them serrated like a saw. Then it breaks the string frequently and throws the remaining strings out of tune.

I go to a luthier and he strips smooth again, but it never lasts long and the problem returns. I use tape between the string and the saddle to improve the durability.

My question is, there's a way to fix it without throwing them away and buying some new ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broken strings are a known risk with Floyd Rose tremolos. It doesn't seem to be particularly related to a worn saddle though.

The standard solutions seem to be:

- taking care when tightening the screws
- oiling the saddle
- changing strings frequently

There are a couple of products designed to address the problem. "Saddle Singers" are inserts that sit between the string and the saddle. "String Savers" are replacement saddles.

Comment: I change my strings once each month and I use 11 gauge, it's a hard string. But I think that Saddle Singers is what I'm searching for. Thank you!